# Least intrusive webcam capture in browser

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, jquery-webcam-plugin

I need to capture webcam images from inside browser. I am planning to use Flash but since am not experienced in it, before jumping into it, I want to ask you experts :

1. Will Flash ask for Webcam permission every time user refreshes the page ? Isn't there some global security setting to allow a website.
2. Is it essential to display the webcam feed on the browser to be able to capture it / take snapshot and upload to server. I totally don't want to show live feed on the webpage, all I want is to take snapshots and upload it in the background.

   - The purpose of above requirement is that we are trying to add proctoring to our online assessment platform, and hence we don't want to reload / ask for permission again every time candidate views a new test page. One alternative can be making the whole site a single page webapp, but definitely that will add quite some overhead.

Comment: I am very sceptical of those points, especially the last sentence in #2.

Comment: Uf, it has been some time I made anything with webcam and Flash but as far as I remember: 1 - YES, it will ask. 2 - NO, you shouldn't need to put it.

Comment: Thanks Fygo. Will validate it.